# explaining reuse variable for lstm network in tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, lstm

I have wrote a code to design long short term memory network in Tensorflow. The code has worked after I made alot of changes and read some comments in this website. 
This part of code is important to explain:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
with tf.variable_scope("conv1"): 
    cell= tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=0.0,    state_is_tuple=True,reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False,scope="conv1")
```

The los function plot is always like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FNYi.png).

Where at some point training loss function decrease and validation loss function increase. I think it must not be like this. I would like to ask if the variable reusing is right in my code? and if you have an idea what is wrong with the loss function plot?

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

I thought maybe I should post my code, so it will be easier to understand because I can't find a solution:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_steps, n_inputs])
y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, n_classes])
weights = {
# (147, 128),tf.random_normal_initializer(mean=0.0, stddev=0.1)
'in': tf.get_variable('W_in',shape=[n_inputs, n_hidden_units],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.5)),
# (128, 5)
'out': tf.get_variable('W_out',shape=[n_hidden_units, n_classes],initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.5))}
biases = {
# (128, )
'in': tf.get_variable('b_in',shape=[n_hidden_units, ],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.5)),
# (5, )
'out': tf.get_variable('b_out', shape=[n_classes, ],initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=0.5))}
 def lstm_cell():
       return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(n_hidden_units, forget_bias=0.0, state_is_tuple=True,reuse=tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)

def RNN(X, weights, biases):
       X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, n_inputs])
       X_in = tf.nn.tanh(tf.matmul(X, weights['in']) + biases['in'])
       X_in=tf.nn.dropout(X_in,keep_prob=0.5)
       X_in = tf.reshape(X_in, [-1, n_steps, n_hidden_units])
       with tf.variable_scope("conv1"):
             cell = lstm_cell()
             cell = tf.contrib.rnn.DropoutWrapper(cell, output_keep_prob=0.5)
             init_state = cell.zero_state(tf.shape(X_in)[0], dtype=tf.float32)
             outputs, final_state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(cell, X_in, initial_state=init_state, time_major=False,scope="conv1")
       outputs = tf.unstack(tf.transpose(outputs, [1,0,2]))
       results = tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']    

       return results

pred = RNN(x, weights, biases)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=pred, labels=y))
train_op = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.0025).minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally if your validation loss begins to increase, it means your network is over fitting on the training data. You can reduce this with regularization, dropout or other methods. You should also try decreasing the overall number of neurons/layers in your network.

Comment: I tried different number of neurons but the plot is the same. I tried dropout with propability equal 0.5 and the previous plot is the result.